# Script Task not aborting the execution on FireError

Tags: ssis

I have the following code in an SSIS Script Task, which is contained in a loop:

```
public void Main()
        {
            System.DateTime beginDate = DateTime.Parse(Dts.Variables["User::BeginDate"].Value.ToString());
            System.DateTime endDate = beginDate.AddMonths(1);


            string strMessage = string.Format("Row count validation failed for the period {0} to {1}. Ods has fewer rows for this period than the source.",
                beginDate,
                endDate);

            Dts.Events.FireError(0, "Row count validation", strMessage, "", 0);

            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
        }
```

When I run this in Visual Studio and an error occurs, an Error event is triggered, the loop terminates and the package execution stops. When I deploy this to an SSIS server and run it, an error event is not triggered, the loop does not terminate and the package does not terminate. Anyone know why?

Comment: Hi, there is a lot messages that script task don't work when deployed, some tried updating sql and package to newer version of visual studio: https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1658166-364-1.aspx

Comment: @Justin - Thanks but the link you reference is over three years old and I am using VS 2017.

Comment: This is new April 27 https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/205198/ssis-not-executing-any-script-task , there is info on google but nothing clear that realy helped solving problem. You version is new so problem somwere else... dot.net version? You need to try and see if just your script don't work or all scripts don't work.

Comment: @Justin - All my script tasks are working, except this one, in this particular situation.

Comment: I don't have a answer, but what I do just search internet for script with FireError function and people who say that script worked. If for you don't gonna work - I change script element to something general like execute task or something with element which can solve you problem...